# loop through XmlNodeList then launch new thread for each

Tags: c#

I'm trying to loop through an XmlNodeList, grab some data out of it then start a new thread that uses this piece of data.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    public void startRun(string kwd)
    {
        doRun run = new doRun();
        run.run(kwd);
    }

    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument searches = new XmlDocument();
        searches.Load("data\\Searches.xml");

        XmlNodeList search = searches.SelectNodes("Searches/search");
        var nodeCount = search.Count;

        for(var i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++)
        {
            string kwd = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(search[i].SelectSingleNode("query").InnerText);
            doRun run = new doRun(this);
            Thread newThread = new Thread( new ThreadStart( startRun(kwd) ) );
        }
    }
```

This isn't working out at all. Visual Studio is saying `Method name expected` for this line:

`Thread newThread = new Thread( new ThreadStart( startRun(kwd) ) );`

How can I pass this parameter into the new thead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach:

To begin with your syntax for creating the delegate is wrong: `new ThreadStart(startRun(kwd))` is not valid syntax. The proper syntax is: `new ThreadStart(startRun)` - using only the method name.

Then, if you are looking to pass a parameter to the thread you should use a [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) delegate instead of a [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) deleagate.

```
Thread newThread = new Thread( new ParameterizedThreadStart(startRun));
```

And start the thread with a call to `Start(...)`:

```
newThread.Start(kwd);
```

And the signature of `startRun` should use an object instead of string in the parameter:

```
public void startRun(object kwdObject)
```

Inside you could cast `kwd` to `string` to use it:

```
public void startRun(object kwdObject)
{
    string kwd = (string)kwdObject;
    // continue to do work..
```

Now, as far as the implementation of `startRun`, it seems like the method itself is redundant. If you have a class called `doRun` (by the way, it's good practice to capitalize the first letter of class names) - then why not just use doRun's run method as the ThreadStart delegate. Unless doRun.run(..) doesn't take an oject in which case your approach of creating a *forwarding* function is ok.

```
doRun run = new doRun();
run.run(kwd);
```

---

**Part2**

Having covered the problems in your code as it is, in general it's advisable to consider using a ThreadPool worker thread instead of manually creating a new thread to execute your task if the tasks you are executing are not long-running tasks (i.e. if you expect the task to complete within a few seconds).

To do so, you could modify your code like this:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++)
  {
      string kwd = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(search[i].SelectSingleNode("query").InnerText);
      ThreadPool.QueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)startRun, kwd);
  }
```

---

**Part 3**

A fully worked example, using ThreadPool threads:

```
public void startRun(object kwd)
{
    doRun run = new doRun();
    run.run((string)kwd);
}

private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument searches = new XmlDocument();
    searches.Load("data\\Searches.xml");

    XmlNodeList search = searches.SelectNodes("Searches/search");
    var nodeCount = search.Count;

    for(var i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++)
    {
        string kwd = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(search[i].SelectSingleNode("query").InnerText);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)startRun, kwd);
        // replace line above with the following two lines if you want to use regular threads
        //  Thread newThread = new Thread((ParameterizedThreadStart)startRun);
        //  newThread.Start(kwd);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startRun), kwd);` is giving me this error: `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart, int)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: did you also modify `startRun` as I mentioned? `startRun` must take an single **object** parameter!

Comment: Yes, I modified startRun to `startRun(object kwdObject)`

Comment: I don't think using ThreadPool would be the best solution for me. I need to restart the same thread once it's finished, until a stop button is pushed. Each thread should take about 0.5-1.5 seconds to complete.

Comment: please see update (part 3) with a worked example. Feel free to comment the line that uses worker threads and uncomment the last two commented lines to use the manual thread version.

Comment: but I would question the assumtion that you have to restart _the same thread_ - in most cases you can safely use a another thread to process data..